# How to store Android app data on server (Google drive or json)

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-storage

I am working on an Android app where the user fills a form and submits it. I want to know which technique to use to store the data. I want to later process this stored data to form reports. Please suggest me the best way to store data and later to produce report.

The form initially will contain one dropbox, date, radio button and edit text.

I found few options below but dont knw how to proceed:
Using JSON
Using Google cloud

I tried code at below link:
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89

But dont know how to run the program as it needs serverside php script. I have XAMPP installed on my machine with Apache server running. I can run normal php code but dont know how to make that php code work with my android app.

I am new to server side data handling

Thank you very much in advance. Please help

Answer (score 0):

since you're working with xampp.you can access your localhost from your android emulator using the ip 10.0.2.2/

you will need to use the AsyncTask class and a JSON parser to send your data to your php script.The JSONparser class will remain constant for most of your whole app. You will only have to change the code in your AsyncTask class depending on what data you want to send and the location(php file ie 10.0.2.2/your_file.php or yourdomainname.com/your_file.php) to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work on server scripting and requires a simple data storage to the cloud then you can try using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)

Basically Parse provides you with a library that your app can use to pass values to the server Parse is managing.